# itunes store - release app in 1 market and then expand

Tags: ios, itunes-store

If I release my app in the United States only, and then at a later date expand and release it to more markets, will my app show up in the recently released list in the new markets when it is released?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't itunes have a forum where you could ask this?

Comment: @Shmiddty, it might, but this question is quite suited to here too. Any somebody here might well know the answer.